# Protractor proxy settings configuration is not passed to Saucelabs

Tags: proxy, protractor, saucelabs

To enable saucelabs proxy to work in older version of protractor, we were overriding sendRequest method by setting host and port in below index.js:

> protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js

Now protractor allows you set the proxy through capabilities object (as shown below) which should be passed to index.js sendRequest new parameter called 'opt_proxy'.

```
capabilities: {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    'proxy': {
        'proxyType': 'manual',
        'httpProxy': 'appproxy.web.abc.com:84'
    },
    "chromeOptions": {
        "args": [
            "--disable-extensions",
            "--test-type"
        ]
    },
    "customData": {
        "usageBracket" : "1",
        "displayName"  : "Chrome",
        "id"    : "CH"
    }
}
```

However, when I am still getting null for opt_proxy. Is there anything I am doing wrong? I even tried passing through CLI using --proxy="" but it still get null.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten my proxy configuration to work with Sauce Labs using the sauceAgent util provided within Protractor. Here is a code snippet from my protractor config file.

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require("https-proxy-agent");
var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent('http://localhost:56193'); //Insert your proxy info here

exports.config = {
  sauceUser: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
  sauceKey: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,
  sauceAgent: agent,
```

Comment: Do I need to keep the proxy setting in capabilities?

Comment: The proxy settings in the capabilities will not be passed to Sauce Labs. If they are required for other aspects of your testing framework then you may want to keep them.

Answer (score -2):

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--proxy-server=socks5://host:port',
      ]
    },
  },
```